# How to authenticate HBase user using java code which is configured with Apache ranger

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, apache-ranger

I am using a ranger for HBase authorization. manually I created users in ranger and I tested. it is working. Now I want to pass the user from   Java code to test the authorization for Hbase.

Comment: What have you tried, and what is the issue?

Comment: it will automatically pass the username from which user you are running the code.